# How to change default setting of vim-clojure-static plugin?

Tags: vim, plugins, clojure, vim-plugin, vimclojure

I'm new in ***clojure*** programming. I'm using ***vim*** editor. I have installed ***vim-clojure-static*** plugin to write better code.
But It's not working as I expected. I want ***two*** spaces indentation for every special keyword.

For example, Here is ***core.clj*** file.

```
(ns hello.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import
    (java.io FileNotFoundException)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")
  (try (slurp (first args))
       (catch FileNotFoundException e (println (.getMessage e)))))
```

This is defualt indentation. I don't like this. I want my code should look like:

```
(ns hello.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import
    (java.io FileNotFoundException)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")
  (try (slurp (first args))
    (catch FileNotFoundException e (println (.getMessage e)))))
```

It means, I want ***two*** spaces indentation for every special keyword ***i.e*** ***try*** in given example.

Meanwhile I'm not sure, Whether I have installed ***plugin** in correct way. Here is my **.vim** directory structure:

```
$ tree ~/.vim/
/home/james/.vim/
|-- autoload
|   `-- pathogen.vim
`-- bundle
    `-- vim-clojure-static
        |-- autoload
        |   `-- clojurecomplete.vim
        |-- clj
        |   |-- dev-resources
        |   |   |-- test-basic-sexp-indent.txt
        |   |   |-- test-inherit-indent.in
        |   |   |-- test-inherit-indent.out
        |   |   |-- test-multibyte-indent.txt
        |   |   |-- test-reader-conditional-indent.in
        |   |   |-- test-reader-conditional-indent.out
        |   |   |-- test-side-effects-in-indentexpr.in
        |   |   `-- test-side-effects-in-indentexpr.out
        |   |-- project.clj
        |   |-- src
        |   |   `-- vim_clojure_static
        |   |       |-- generate.clj
        |   |       `-- test.clj
        |   |-- test
        |   |   `-- vim_clojure_static
        |   |       |-- indent_test.clj
        |   |       `-- syntax_test.clj
        |   `-- vim
        |       `-- test-runtime.vim
        |-- doc
        |   `-- clojure.txt
        |-- ftdetect
        |   `-- clojure.vim
        |-- ftplugin
        |   `-- clojure.vim
        |-- indent
        |   `-- clojure.vim
        |-- LICENSE.txt
        |-- README.markdown
        `-- syntax
            `-- clojure.vim

16 directories, 23 files
```

Here is my ***vimrc*** file:

```
$ cat ~/.vimrc
set autoindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

can anyone tell me, Where I'm wrong? How can I make autoindent with spaces ***two**? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the documentation here: https://github.com/guns/vim-clojure-static,
you need to add the `try` keyword to the list with a command like

`let g:clojure_fuzzy_indent_patterns = ['^with', '^def', '^let', '^try']`

I hope it will help, I didn't try it